# Big O Notation for the permutations of a list of words

Tags: algorithm, big-o

What would be the big O notation of the length of the list of permutations of the characters of a list of words of lenght n?

I just do not know how to express that because it would be like n! for each word where n is the characters of that word but O(n!) is just the complexity of a single word, not a list of n words.

Also, every word may have different sizes.

An example:

Let's say that I have the words "abc", "abcd" and "abcde". If I have to create the permutations of each word, I would end up with a list of lists of strings with lengths of 6, 24 and 120 i.e. the permutations of "abc" will be in the first list, the permutations of the second word will be in the second and so on and so on.

If I use an permutation iterator, how much time will it take to generate all those lists?

Comment: Depends on the algorithm..

Comment: @Blorgbeard I'm sorry, I meant bruteforce it.

Comment: Define "bruteforce"...

Comment: Does the length of the words actually depend on n?

Comment: @RishiG no, the n in n! means the number of permutations of a single word were n is the lenght of the word. E.g. in the String "abc" n is 3.

Comment: what does the algorithm exactly do? are you supposed to split the whole string into words and compute all the permutations word by word or are you supposed to permute the initial string but only by permuting the words themselves and and exchanging characters between words?

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk I just added an example.

Comment: since BigO represents an upper bound then you can safely say that there are ```O(k*n!)``` strings where ```n``` is the length of the longest input word.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk great! That was what I wanted, but did not know how to write it. Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Do you only want to generate the list of words, or also generate the actual words? That can make a great difference in a lazy language :-)

Comment: @Bergi well, In the first try, generate the actual words. Then, in the next iteration of the kata, use a lazy sequence to only get a few ones that match a certain predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since BigO represents an upper bound then you can safely say that there are `O(k*n!)` strings where `n` is the length of the longest input word (since in the worst case all the strings will have the same length then there will be exactly `k*n!` permutations, in a better case with variable lengths the number will be `< k*n!` but the notation `O(k*n!)` still holds).

If you have some additional information regarding the distribution of those lengths we can try to do a tighter bound :-)

@Edit: as @Aron pointed out this is a pretty (I'm not gonna get very formal here) tight upper bound if you do not have repeating chars. With repeating chars it's still a valid upper bound but a tighter bound would be `O(k*a^n)` where `a` is the size of our alphabet (26 if you are using English, more than 110,000 if you are using Unicode) this will eventually be tighter than `O(k*n!)`. This holds because at each of the `n` slots in a word you can place one of `a` characters and notice that with repeating chars `a` might be smaller (even much smaller) than `n`.

Comment: @ElderMael Palindromes are impossible, since you are dealing with Permutations and `n!`, since no letter is ever repeated.

Comment: @ElderMael I mean that `n!` comes from no repeating letters. Therefore there are no palindromes. You got the wrong end of the stick when you put factorial into your question. You actually want `Sum 26 ^ n`

Comment: @Aron it's still ```O(k*n!)``` even if you allow repetitions. You have 2 cases: word with no repeating characters which has exactly n! permutations and a word with repeating characters which will have ```n!/x``` where ```x``` is the number of permutations possible from repeating characters but that's always smaller than n! A clever algorithm will check if all chars are distinct and then you can go down to ```O(n!/x)```

Comment: That reduces to 26^n. The sum of the two problem spaces. You can't say that the sum of n is O(n) because n is O(n), its damn well O(n^2) and you know it!

Comment: 26 if you are talking only about English alphabet but yes it can be said to be ```k^n``` if we have repeating characters where ```k``` is constant representing the size of our alphabet and it will be a tighter upper bound.